# How to install Ubuntu Software Center on Ubuntu Gnome 17.04?

Tags: gnome, software-installation, software-center, 17.04

How to install `Ubuntu Software Center` on Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 Zasty Zepus (**NOTE:** Different from `Ubuntu Software`)?

As we know, Ubuntu GNOME comes with `GNOME Software` by default. However, I'd need the old `Ubuntu Software Center` for the sake of few packages that can be found there. I already tried to search through `Synaptic Package Manager`, but with no luck. I also tried to run `sudo apt-get install software-center`, but it resulted into the following:

```
Package software-center is not available, but is referred to by 
another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'software-center' has no installation candidate
```

What I am particularly looking for, is `GStreamer plugins for mms, wavpack, quicktime, musepack (thorugh Ubuntu Software Center)`.

Thanks!

Comment: Surely it's easier just to install those old packages through the terminal?

Comment: @Tim Can you help me with the command lines to run? :-P

Comment: Well if you want to install (say) chromium, you use `sudo apt-get install chromium`. What do you want to install?

Comment: yes search for terminal or download and install options of each.

Comment: Ubuntu software center is deprecated in favor of gnome software. What particular feature you need in that software which isn't in gnome-software?

Comment: @Anwar Packages that cannot be found from `GNOME Software`. More specifically, I need to install `GStreamer plugins for mms, wavpack, quicktime, musepack (thorugh Ubuntu Software Center)`

Comment: @Jayaguru-Shishya It would be much much easier if you could just express your original problem. This has turned into a [x-y problem](http://xyproblem.info). Must you install it via software center ? If any other method servers the purpose what about that?

Answer (score 2):

"software-center": The new package name is `gnome-software` http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=software&searchon=names

The old software-center http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/software-center/ ... The source packages, version software-center_1.0.2.tar.gz ... to     software-center_13.10.orig.tar.gz ( Patches for the latest version : software-center_13.10-0ubuntu4.1.debian.tar.gz )

Comment: Well that is a partial answer. If you look at the list you will see that package the op is requesting is indeed called "software-center" . As of 17.04, however, software center is no longer available / maintained and ubuntu shifted to gnome-software. The only option to install would, IMO, be to install software-center from source, however I have no idea if it will work in 17.04

Comment: @KnudLarsen Exactly as @bodhi.zazen put it. I am looking for [Ubuntu Software Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Software_Center), the one before Ubuntu moved to `GNOME Software` (in Unity desktop known as `Ubuntu Software`).

@bodhi.zazen Can you please advise me how to install from source? I am ready to give a shot at least, even though it wasn't guaranteed that it will work.

 Thanks!

Comment: The old software-center : See my edited answer.

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thanks! May I ask, which one of the three is to install the latest (though now unmaintained) `Ubuntu Software Center`?

Comment: »» which one of the three is to install «« : I can't answer that. I use `synaptic` only. Always has. Is reliable, and shows all ~40,000 packages.